# Get Linq Group into a User Defined Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-group

I am working on a c# project and writing a LINQ query, in this query I need to create a group, but I know I want to use that group type, but the type of the group gives me some trouble as I am not able to cast it to my desired type.

My Query is

```
from emp in employees
join dept in departments
on emp.EmpID equals dept.EmpID
group dept by dept.EmpID into groupSet
select new mycustomType
{
    Department = groupSet
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the signature of any of your types. We can only be guessing how your desired type might look. Next time you ask a question make sure you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Anyway, according to your example here's how this custom type should look like:

```
public class MyCustomType
{
    public IGrouping<int, Department> Department { get; set; }
}
```

where `Department` is the type of elements inside the `departments` collection and it assumes that `EmpID` is of type integer.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employees = ...
IEnumerable<Department> departments = ...

IEnumerable<MyCustomType> result = 
    from emp in employees
    join dept in departments
    on emp.EmpID equals dept.EmpID
    group dept by dept.EmpID into groupSet
    select new MyCustomType
    {
        Department = groupSet
    };
```